# How to render a progress element from right to left?

Tags: css, html, progress-bar

I have a progress bar that show from left to right. I need to make another which is same style progress but will show from right to left.

Here is my style definition:

```
progress, progress[role] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    background-size: auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
 progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
     background-color: grey;
     border-radius: 2px;
     box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
 }
 progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
    background-image:
        -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, 
                               transparent 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 33%, 
                               rgba(0,0, 0, .1) 66%, transparent 66%),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(top, 
                               rgba(255, 255, 255, .25), 
                               rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #09c, #f44);
    border-radius: 2px; 
    background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%; 
}

.valuebar {
    position: relative;
}
.valuebar h3 {
    color: #fff;
    left: 1em;
    line-height: 1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I used sample from the web which uses `::-webkit-progress-value`.

How can I make it render from right to left?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, many elements flip their horizontal rendering when their `direction` attribute is changed from `ltr` (which is the default) to `rtl`, which stands for right-to-left (to be compatible with right-to-left languages, such as Arabic or Hebrew).

The `<progress>` element is not different. Just give CSS something to cling to (such as a special class) and set its `direction: rtl;`.

Here is a small snippet based on the code you posted.

```css
/* this is the important bit */
progress.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
progress,
progress[role] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  background-size: auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 66%, transparent 66%), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, .25), rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #09c, #f44);
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
}
.valuebar {
  position: relative;
}
.valuebar h3 {
  color: #fff;
  left: 1em;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<progress value="59" max="100">59%</progress>
<br />
<progress class="rtl" value="59" max="100">59%</progress>
```

I don't know what is your markup, as you did not post it, but you may need to adjust the `.valuebar` positioning.

Here is a [code pen](https://codepen.io/ImBobby/pen/keaHp) you can toy with.